# I want to make display block when there are 17 letters into input

Tags: javascript

So I'm playing with my knowledge around javascript and making form, so i made password input into html and gave maxlength 17 and when someone writes 17 letters i want div to comeout but its not working

```
function myFunction(){
    var letters = document.getElementsByClassName("inp4");
    var l = letters[0].value.length;
    var wdw = document.getElementById("pas");
    if (l >= 17) {
        wdw.style.display = "block";
    }
}

<input type="password" class="inp4" maxlength="17" placeholder=" Password" >     
<!-- javascript when maxlength 17 -->
<div id="pas">
    <p>maximum amount of letters is 17</p>
</div>
<input type="password" class="inp5" maxlength="17" placeholder=" Repeat your password">

#pas {
    width:200px;
    height:40px;
    background-color:#8DC3D8;
    z-index: 1;
    position: absolute;
    border-radius:5%;
    font-size:0.9rem;   
    padding:5px;
    text-align: center;
    font-family: Verdana, Geneva, sans-serif;
    color:white;
    left:-4.5%;
    bottom:51%;
    display:none;
}
```

Comment: what do you mean come out? you want the div to disappear at that point?

Comment: No i want to appear

Comment: can you show your html too, so we can better assist you?

Comment: here it is i also added css if you want to

Answer (score 0):

You need to attacht your function to input event listener, such as `onkeypress`
So on every keypress you check the number of characters in your input field
See the code snippet below

```js
function myFunction(val) {
 var wdw = document.getElementById("pas");
 if (val.length >= 17) {
  wdw.style.display = "block";
 }
}
```

```css
#pas {
width:200px;
height:60px;
background-color:#8DC3D8;
z-index: 1;
position: absolute;
border-radius:5%;
font-size:0.9rem;   
padding:5px;
text-align: center;
font-family: Verdana, Geneva, sans-serif;
color:white;
top: 100px;
display:none;
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Password</title>
</head>
<body> 

<input type="password" class="inp4" maxlength="17" placeholder=" Password" onkeypress="myFunction(this.value)" > <!-- javascript when maxlength 17 -->
<div id="pas">
 <p>maximum amount of letters is 17</p>
</div>
<input type="password" class="inp5" maxlength="17" placeholder=" Repeat your password">

</body>
 </html>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want the `<div id="pas">` to show up when the password equals 17 characters you can do this in your JS if you use jQuery...

```
$('.inp4').keydown(function() {
    let length = $('.inp4').value.length;

    if(length === 17) $('#pas').hide();
    else $('#pas').show();
});
```